# Does SO have a mechanism to batch fix links?

Tags: feature-request, questions

The Qt Project has undergone some change from Nokia to Digia. It also introduced the open governance model, aka. Qt Project. Having said that, the infrastructure has also changed.

Among other things the Jira issue tracker links became broken. The links should be changed from:

```
http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-4046
```

to:

```
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-4046
```

I have manually fixed some in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963072/qmake-x64-makespec-for-x64-visual-studio-solution). Searching [search SO for old Qt bug links](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbugreports.qt.nokia.com%2Fbrowse%2FQTBUG-) revealed that there are 56 more dead links left, which I don't want to fix manually.

Does Stack Overflow provide a way of fixing this "automatically" once and for all, i.e. by issuing a pattern replace?

Comment: Hmmm, might as well flag most of those answers as Not an answer. Most of them go like: *see fix here: [link]*

Comment: well, of course there are "bad" answers that don't get better when the link is updated. But for this case it is known what the broken links are and it would be quite easy to batch fix it on the database. Stackoverflow should actually even have an automatic watch for similar links and automatically suggest to update all other links when one of the group is fixed by a user

Comment: For 50 or so hits we just edit that out... but the specific case from your question requires more cleanup up. I might as well close question with the reason: no longer reproduceable. But I wait for some agreement on that...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying with 'For 50 or so hits we just edit that out... but the specific case from your question requires more cleanup up'. The QT bugs that I mentioned are just an example, the question is whether Stack overflow has a mechanism to fix such things. There certainly are other projects that have bug reports and move from one domain to another.

Comment: Yep, there are some examples like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141203/blogs-sun-com-is-dead)... all hand edited...

Comment: exactly, close this bug as duplicate of the other. But why hand edited? Is there no api or keyboard shortcut macro magic possible? If not, why was it not invented for SO when that had happened? :)

Comment: Looking at one question, links to specific pages of the docs at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/ are now also broken, instead redirecting to the root. It's quite possible that [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.qt.nokia.com%2F) is a truer count of the broken links.

Comment: @SachaGuyer maybe because the dev team had more pressing things todo and maybe because it is not always a search/replace (as you can learn from the sun -> oracle debacle). If it needs a human you better leave it to the community.

Comment: It might well be that the dev team did not have time then, it apparently is not an often occurring issue. I'm not familiar with database programming, but think that a database wide string replacement should not be so difficult and should not "need" humans.

Comment: [It is hard to get right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230313/158100)

Comment: +1. I support this proposal. Now, all the edited threads come up in the active tab, although not in the newest. To clarify, it does not bother me, and I appreciate the work, but it is more work for the contributors than it could be, and it would potentially distract less people. I imagine this automation would be a manageable task to resolve for the devs.

Comment: Most of the docs seem to redirect @OGHaza... if they didn't then you'd actually want to use [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.qt.nokia.com%22), which is a lot scarier.

Comment: I edited the links in the posts that resulted from the seach query in the post from the OP...

Comment: It should *now* be `https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-4046` (!)